# How do you see a good Spring+Hibernate DAO module design?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

First, we create classes that represent db entities, ok, done.
Let's say we use Hibernate session factory and JPA annotations.

Now we must create a DAO: getUserById, getAllUsers() etc.

What do you recommend about transaction management, session factory, how a good design to be made?

Comment: It may be useful to know a little history of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447003/dao-spring-and-hibernate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Make the DAO generic. See the [Don't repeat the DAO](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao.html) article.
2. Transaction management should be spring-managed. Use a `JpaTransactionManager`. Transactions can be marked in two ways, and they should mark methods of the service classes, not the DAO:

   - using `@Transactional` on each transactional method (in combination with `<tx:annotation-driven />` in `applicationContext.xml`)
   - using `<tx:advice>` and the appropriate `<aop:config>`
3. Use [`OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.html) or [`OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor`](http://apollo89.com/java/spring-framework-2.5.3/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.html) in order to avoid `LazyInitializationException`

[Read this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html) for more details.